# adding a site template : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: file-upload, site, template, solution

I have created a site template named poMail.wsp
and when I try to add it to the catalog via "upload solution" I get this error :

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.UploadPage.OnSubmitSolution(SPLongOperation
>   longOperation, SPFile file) +40
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.UploadPage.OnSubmit(Object o,
>   EventArgs e) +685
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton.OnServerClick(EventArgs e)
>   +114    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +28
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer

i ran Timer Service Recycle job (found this on a forum) and then tried uploading with another acount that has full control over the site collection, and it worked like a charm.
i hope it helps someone ;)